# WiFi thermostat. No c wire

Tags: wiring, hvac

I just bought a vacation home and I want to keep pipes from freezing in winter.  The thermostat has R,R,O, black(W label) and G. I bought Honeywell RTH9585WF smart thermostat.  Can I hook up AC and heat? Though only controlling heat remotely.  WITH a 24v transformer?  Option B (approved by Honeywell) is to switch out  thermostat each change of seasons.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your existing thermostat cable have any spare/unused wires?

Comment: A wire on O makes it seems you have a reversing valve, so a heat pump rather than AC. Either way it's still possible to control heat only using wires connecting R,C, & W, but giving o taking advice of how to do it is risky without seeing wiring diagrams from AC/HP, furnace, and existing stat terminations.

Comment: Brands/models of _all_ equipment involved, as well as clear, focused, well lit pictures of the wiring on all those devices will go a _long_ way toward helping us help you. Just [edit] your post to include them

Comment: Got it.  I’m not at property now.  I know heat is Weil Mclane boiler.   I don’t know AC.   I’ll take pics and find out manufacturer and model nos.   I’m pretty sure no spare/unused wires

Comment: Added a few pics (I have more).  I DO have spare wire (?make C wire?).  I was looking at smart WiFi t stats that don’t need C wire (ecobee, sensi?).  If I do add/make c wire, where do I attach at the boiler (Zone valves, transformer). I’m looking for a board that lists a c-wire.  I do have voltage tester/meter.

Comment: I was wrong about O….it’s yellow

Comment: I understand that Rc is cooling, R (or Rh) is heat, yellow is cooling, white (or in my case black) is heat, and green is fan (AC uses fan only)

Comment: @Drewp -- can you post the model number of your boiler please, as well as the wiring diagram or make & model for your AC's air handler?

Comment: You’ll have to wait.  I’m not at the property

Comment: And just to clarify, the t stat in question is the “hall” (zone valve). One zone/ thermostat/valve is for the MB only (heat only).